# Make button recognize text in JTextField

Tags: java, if-statement, checkbox, jtextfield

My goal here is to make two checkboxes become enabled when someone types the word "Physique" into a certain JTextField.

SO:

```
Press button
Button reads text in JTextField
if text in field is equal to Physique
then enable Checkboxes Three and Four.
```

However, I cannot make it respond when text is entered in the JTextField

```
String greatOne = skillGreat1JTextField.getText();

if ( greatOne.equals( "Physique" ) ) {

        physStress3CheckBox.setEnabled( true );
        physStress4CheckBox.setEnabled( true );

    }
```

This triggers when I press an Apply button, but for some reason. This if statement doesn't seem to perform because the Checkboxes never become enabled when Physique is entered into the JTextField

Anyone have a clue why this won't perform? I'm at a loss.

[EDIT]

Here's some more of the code. When I press a button named Apply, this should perform.

```
public void applyJButtonActionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {

    String greatOne = skillGreat1JTextField.getText();

    if ( greatOne.equals( "Physique" ) ) {

        physStress3CheckBox.setEnabled( true );
        physStress4CheckBox.setEnabled( true );

    } 
}
```

That's the IF statement, here's the code for the button:

```
applyJButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
                applyJButtonActionPerformed( event );
            }
        }
    );
```

Also, in reply to Rudi, Should I be using an OnClickListener? I've been using an ActionListener.

[LAST EDIT]

I've figured it out. It turns out my issue was a conflict with something that happens **later** in the event, I just took out the line of code that was **Turning them back off** after it had just turned them on. Thanks everyone for all of your help.

```
System.out.println("Some text");
```

This one line of text solved my entire problem. Thanks again everyone! You've saved my FATE games.

Comment: Just to clarify, where is the above code? Is it inside a button's OnClickListener? Also, are you getting any exceptions? If you put `System.out.println("Is running")` into the if statement, is it printing?

Comment: provide more code, where are you calling this if statement?

Comment: Edited my original post to reflect the extra questions.

Comment: @Snerfmonster - No your correct in assuming that ActionListener is probably a better choice than OnClickListener. From your code though, it looks as though it should be working. Are you getting any exceptions? Also, I am assuming you don't mean ticking the check box when you say enable.

Comment: I think OP meant to `tick` the checkboxes. In which case he should use `setSelected(true)`.

Comment: No, they're currently set to be disabled. I'm making a character sheet so the players **CAN'T** select the checkbox until it's been enabled. I want it to enable when they choose Physique as a skill.

However the IF statement doesn't seem to run. Even when the parameters for it are true.

Comment: @Snerfmonster - In which case you might want to test each section of code with a `System.out.println("Some text");` statement. Put one inside the ActionListener, one inside your ApplyJButton method and one inside the if statement and see how far your code is running to. I find it incredibly hard to believe that an if statement wouldn't run even if it were `if(true){  }`.

Comment: I like @Rudi don't see anything wrong with the code. The string `equals()` is case sensitive. Make sure it is **Physique**. Use `equalsIgnoreCase` for case insensitive.

Comment: Okay! I've confirmed, the IF statement is running; however, it isn't setting those checkboxes to setEnabled( true );

Comment: Thanks Rudi and Anonymous. The
    System.out.println("Some text");
Solved my problem. Just a simple logic error. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Snerfmonster - Glad you sorted your issue. Don't forget to post and accept your own answer with a little detail on what was happening to help any future browsers of Stack who stumble on this question :)

Comment: Of course! Working on it now! I think it makes me wait a while because I'm new here though... ASAP I'll get my answer posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. The problem was within the same action.

I had an IF statement later in the button (That didn't seem important at the time) that referred to a different Checkbox that would Unlock all of the skill buttons:

```
if ( !unlockSkillsJCheckBox.isSelected() ) {
        skillSuperb1JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillSuperb2JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillSuperb3JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillSuperb4JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillSuperb5JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGreat2JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGreat3JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGreat4JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGreat5JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGood3JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGood4JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillGood5JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillFair4JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillFair5JTextField.setEditable( false );
        skillAverage5JTextField.setEditable( false );

        consEXTRA2JTextField.setEditable( false );

        physStress3CheckBox( false ); //THE PROBLEM LIES HERE.
        physStress4Checkbox( false ); //THE PROBLEM LIES HERE.

        mentStress3CheckBox.setEnabled( false );
        mentStress4CheckBox.setEnabled( false );

    }
```

The if statement was running perfectly and functioning as it was supposed to. But because of those two lines, as soon as they turned on, they turned right back off again.

Although I did learn that System.out.println("Some text"); can be your best friend. Use this to test for logic errors.

My error was a logic error that happens later in the same action listener I had.
Hope this helps anyone having my same problem! Thanks Stack!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable/disable check boxes **when you click on an "apply" button**, you can follow [@anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23248176/604478) advice and put the test on an `ActionListener`.

If you want to enable/disable check boxes **when some text is typed**, you have to put a listener on the text field. Basically, every time the text changes, the component must fire an event to check the word and enable/disable the check boxes. You can do a thing like this in the init part of your code:

```
skillGreat1JTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

   @Override
   public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
      checkWord();
   }

   @Override
   public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
      checkWord();
   }

   @Override
   public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
      checkWord();
   }

   private void checkWord() {
      String greatOne = skillGreat1JTextField.getText();
      if (greatOne.equals("Physique")) {
         physStress3CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
         physStress4CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
      }
   }
});
```

You can find some guide on on listeners [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/), and specifically on document listeners [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have registered an ActionListener to the `apply` button. It should be something like this...

```
applyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             if("Physique".equals(skillGreat1JTextField.getText())) {
                 physStress3CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                 physStress4CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
             }
         }
      });
```

Comment: Although your code is good, it's implied in the question that they already have a similar setup. `This triggers when I press an Apply button`

Comment: @Rudi saying is one thing. Actually implemented it correctly is another. I just wanna make sure OP had registered a proper ActionListener because after all, it had `unresponsive` tag.

Comment: I've posted the code for the Button in an EDIT. The actionlistener is properly applied, does **other** actions just fine. But that if statement doesn't seem to run, even if the tester is true.